# Google Maps v3 OverlayView.getProjection()

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I cannot seem to figure out why the object returned by getProjection() is undefined. Here is my code:

```
 // Handles the completion of the rectangle
  var ne = recBounds.getNorthEast();
  var sw = recBounds.getSouthWest();
  $("#map_tools_selat").attr( 'value', sw.lat() );
  $("#map_tools_nwlat").attr( 'value', ne.lat() );
  $("#map_tools_selng").attr( 'value', ne.lng() );
  $("#map_tools_nwlng").attr( 'value', sw.lng() );

  // Set Zoom Level
  $("#map_tools_zoomlevel").attr( 'value', HAR.map.getZoom()+1 );
  document.getElementById("map_tools_centerLat").value = HAR.map.getCenter().lat();
  document.getElementById("map_tools_centerLong").value = HAR.map.getCenter().lng(); 

  // All this junk below is for getting pixel coordinates for a lat/lng  =/
  MyOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  MyOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() { }
  MyOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() { }
  MyOverlay.prototype.draw = function() { }
  function MyOverlay(map) { this.setMap(map); }
  var overlay = new MyOverlay(HAR.map);
  var projection = overlay.getProjection();
  // END - all the junk
  var p = projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(recBounds.getCenter());
  alert(p.x+", "+p.y);
```

My error is: **Cannot call method 'fromLatLngToContainerPixel' of undefined**

Comment: BTW: I pasted the jquery portion to show that my map object (HAR.map) does work.  I have confirmed many times that the getCenter() and getZoom() function are in fact returning proper values.  So the HAR.map object is legit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually, i the reason why this happens is because the projection object is created after the map is idle after panning / zooming. So, a better solution is to listen on the **idle** event of the **google.maps.Map** object, and get a reference to the projection there:

```
// Create your map and overlay
var map;
MyOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
MyOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() { }
MyOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() { }
MyOverlay.prototype.draw = function() { }
function MyOverlay(map) { this.setMap(map); }

var overlay = new MyOverlay(map);
var projection;

// Wait for idle map
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
   // Get projection
   projection = overlay.getProjection();
})
```

Comment: Awesome! I need to try this out.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of figured out what was going on. Even though it is still not crystal clear why this happens, I know that I had to instantiate the variable "overlay" right after instantiating my google map (HAR.map).  So I practically moved that code snippet into my HAR class and now i use:

```
HAR.canvassOverlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel( recBounds.getCenter() );
```

So now, every time I create a map via my class "HAR" I also have a parallel OverlayView object within my class.

The Error could have been with losing scope of my class object, but I think it was more of the map event "projection_changed" not being fired.  I got a hint from the map API docs for map class, under method getProjection():

"[Returns the current Projection. If the map is not yet initialized (i.e. the mapType is still null) then the result is null. Listen to projection_changed and check its value to ensure it is not null.](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)"

**If you are getting the similar issue, make sure that you assign your overlayView.setMAP( YOUR_MAP_OBJECT ) closely after instantiating the map object.**

Comment: I also had this problem, and it was because I didn't have any this.setMap() at all. Thx.