# google maps api v3: top and left pixel position of marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to retrieve the top and left position of marker (in pixels) in google map api v3. How can this be done? I know that there are some hints on using `fromLatLngToDivPixel()`, but may I know how it works? example?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538681/how-to-call-fromlatlngtodivpixel-in-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: Do you mean the pixel coordinates within the div? Please update the question so that it's clear.

Answer (score 5):

You mean the coordinates in pixels within the div? Look at http://qfox.nl/notes/116

```
overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);
var point = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latLng);
```

or

```
var point = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(latLng);
```

Ugly indeed. Much easier in v2, where these methods were directly methods of `GMap2` object. **Another flaw of google api v3!**

Comment: Do you need to initialize a new overlay every time you want to get a pixel reading? Or can you reuse the same overlay (even if the map has changed zooms)?

Answer (score 1):

If you facing problem having the overlay `undefined`, that's because the object is created after the map is `idle`.

Better call this within event listener, full explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6657723/4026345