# How can I restrict google map from repeating in react-google-maps

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am plotting different markers on different locations on the map and then drawing polylines from markers to markers. since the map is repeating the markers are repeating as well and so the lines go in all direction in order to find the shortest path on the map.

Even if we optimize the markers, the markers won't repeat but the polylines are drawn weirdly if the markers are far apart from each other on the map.

Is there a way we can restrict map from repeating itself?

Comment: Add some code to your question that demonstrates what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

You should restrict `minZoom` to 1 and disable map movement on that zoom level.
Have you seen these SO answers?

[Display world map with no repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498210/display-world-map-with-no-repeats)
[Google Maps API V3: Bound world to fit area and disable map repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574222/google-maps-api-v3-bound-world-to-fit-area-and-disable-map-repeat)