# Change Google Map position so that the marker location is not in the center

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I want to change my google map (marker position) to right

*current marker location:*
[image: current marker location]

*I want marker location here:*
[image: I want marker location here]

here is my code

```
        var uluru = {lat: 22.298337, lng: 114.174358};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 16,
                center: uluru
            });
            var image ="assets/images/marker.png";
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map,
                icon: image

            });
```

Comment: I think this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305876/how-to-move-the-center-position-of-google-map should help you.

Comment: Subtract some units in longitude from the variable map

Comment: Example: center: {lat: uluru.lat, lng: uluru.lng - 0.004206}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate location for the map center, adjust that so the marker appears where you want it to:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 16,
  center: {lat: 22.298337, lng: 114.17}
});
```

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: 22.298337,
    lng: 114.174358
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: {lat: 22.298337, lng: 114.17}
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```