# Testing Google Maps with Jasmine

Tags: google-maps, jasmine

I have an application which relies on Google Maps, and I am writing unit tests using Jasmine and Karma. I have a fake Google.maps.Map instance which I use to test my code:

*myFunction*

```
var myFunction(map) {
  var foo = false;
  var projection = map.getProjection();
  // ... do dome stuff
  return foo;
}
```

*tests*

```
describe('myFunction() {

 var fakeMap = function() {
    var map;
    // create fake DOM element for map
    mapCanvas = document.createElement("div");
    mapCanvas.setAttribute("id", 'map-canvas');
    // map instance
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas);
    return map
  }

  it("should test my function", function () {
    var map = fakeMap();
    foo = myfunction(map);
    expect(foo).toBe(true);
  })

});
```

However, this fails as in `myFuntion`,  `projection` is `undefined`.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710745/google-maps-v3-overlayview-getprojection) that the google maps instance needs to be idle before `getProjection` will return correctly, so I tried this:

```
it("should test my function", function () {
  var map = fakeMap();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    foo = myfunction(map);
    expect(foo).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

**EDIT** and this:

```
it("should test my function", function () {
  var map = fakeMap();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'projection_changed', function() {
    foo = myfunction(map);
    expect(foo).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

But in this case the test is never executed, presumably because the map never reaches `idle` or `projection_changed` state.

**EDIT**

I also tried to trigger the event manually:

```
it("should test my function", function () {
  var map = fakeMap();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'projection_changed', function() {
    foo = myfunction(map);
    expect(foo).toBe(true);
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'projection_changed');
});
```

How can I test with a `Map` instance which will return all it's methods as expected in the functioning application?

Comment: You wrote: `I read that the google maps instance needs to be idle before getProjection will return correctly`.  The getProjection method will be available after the `projection_changed` event.

Comment: OK. So should I use `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'projection_changed', function() {})` instead of `idle`? Do I need to trigger that event manually?

Comment: I tried with `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'projection_changed', function() {})`, and used `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'projection_changed');` but no joy :(

Comment: What is the trigger 'projection_changed' for?

Comment: Because using just `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'projection_changed', function() { # ..execute test})`, the test is never executed, so I assume that `projection_changed` never happens. So I try to trigger it manually, but still nothing.

Comment: Should I perhaps be treating this as an async call, and use Jasmine's `done()` function?